# Sorting collection in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have dates in a calendar and am accessing them with the below, they have a category relationship with a Category table and a relationship with a CalEvent table.

```
$cal_dates = CalDate::whereBetween('date', array($from, $to))
                ->orderBy('date')
                ->orderBY('start')
                ->get();
```

This returns a list sorted by start date within a range. All good so far and a returned row looks like the below, I can access Category and CalEvent fine i.e. `$cal_date->CalEvent->description`.

```
{
 "id":"406",
 "cal_event_id":"77",
 "start":"00:00:00",
 "finish":"00:00:00",
 "date":"2014-04-06",
 "created_by":"0",
 "updated_by":"0",
 "created_at":"2013-09-21 04:43:25",
 "updated_at":"2013-09-21 04:43:25"
}
```

What I need to is an object like below for my view with the relationships to `Category` and `Cal_Dates` table intact:

```
 cal_dates
    '12th Feb 2014'
        'Array of dates related to category 1 for 12th Feb'
        'Array of all other dates not related to category 1 for 12th Feb'
    '13th Feb 2014'
        'Array of dates related to category 1 for 13th Feb'
        'Array of all other dates not related to category 1 for 13th Feb'
    ...
```

Any advice much appreciated...

Comment: Hi, what is '12th Feb 2014'? created_at, updated_at?

Comment: It is a column in CalDate -, i.e. $cal_date->date = 2014-04-06

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$cal_dates = $cal_dates->sortBy(function($cal_date)
{
    return $cal_date->date;
});
```

**or modify your query:**

```
$cal_dates = CalDate::with('category')
                ->whereBetween('date', array($from, $to))
                ->orderBy('date')
                ->orderBY('start')
                ->get();
```

---

Then in your view you can access the relationship like the following:

```
@foreach($cal_dates as $cal_date)

   <li> {{ $cal_date->date }} </li>
   <!-- category data -->
   <li> {{ $cal_date->category->something }}

@endforeach
```